# How to set expiration date of session token in parse with javascript?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm setting up a dashboard and the admin is able to login an change there the date. He also can logout and my security is at this point fine enough.

But if the user forgets to logout the sessiontoken is by default valid for one year. So how can I change the expiration date of my session token in Javascript from one year to one day for example?

I know it is possible cause I found some [git issues](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/997) about it but I really don't get it how I can implement it in my code and hope some of you can help me to understand it.

Thank you

Comment: are you using cookie-session npm or something? If you are using it, you can just set the `maxAge` to whatever length you want

Comment: I save my session with window.sessionStorage.
In the documentation I found that the token should be deleted after closing the tab. But that does not happen. Is it better to use cookies for session storage?